# compressing a string with repeating symbols

Tags: python, compression

I'm learning python and recently I was challenged by an exercise to compress a string. The **input** goes like '**aaaabbcccca**' the **output** has to be '**a4b2c4a1**'. I did it, but I have a feeling that my solution is rather clumsy. I would like to know, what would be your answer to the task.
My code is:

```
a = input()
l = int(len(a))
c = int()
b = str()
i = 0
while c <l:
    if a[i] == a[c]:
        c += 1
    else:
        b += (a[i] + str(c-i))
        i = c
b += (a[i] + str(c-i))
print(b)
```

Comment: It is better suited for codereview

Comment: This is called run-length-encoding... IIRC there's quite some questions on codereview about this kind of problem already. You may want to check them for inspiration: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=run+length+encoding

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative one(ish) liner:

```
import itertools

a = "aaaabbcccca"
print "".join(["%s%u" % (g[0], len(g)) for g in [list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby(a)]])
```

Which prints:

```
a4b2c4a1
```

To see how this works, you can split the line up into its components to get:

```
groups = [list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby(a)]
print groups

lengths = ["%s%u" % (g[0], len(g)) for g in groups]
print lengths

print "".join(lengths)
```

This prints the following:

```
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'], ['a']]
['a4', 'b2', 'c4', 'a1']
a4b2c4a1
```

Alternatively you could make use of k and g at the same time:

```
print "".join(["%s%u" % (k, len(list(g))) for k,g in itertools.groupby(a)])
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation of the code. There is one thing still not clear for me. What 'k' stands for in 'groups = [list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby(a)]'

Comment: If the look up the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for `itertools.groupby()`, they call it k for key, and g for group. So k would be 'a' and g would end up being 'aaaa'.

Answer (score 0):

Out of my head I would do it in a similar way:

```
s = 'aaaabbcccca'
out = ''
c = 1

for i in range(len(s)):
    if i < len(s)-1 and s[i] == s[i+1]:
        c += 1
    else:
        out += s[i] + str(c)
        c = 1
print out
```

But I guess I on the page provided by [Vogel612](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1803692/vogel612) there are a lot more examples, [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9721/list-splitting-for-rle-compression-algorithm/9728#9728) is a nice to mention.

I modified the example from there (which uses [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)) to match your input string:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> src = 'aaaabbcccca'
>>> print ''.join([a + str(b) for a, b in [(k, sum(1 for _ in g)) for k,g in groupby(src)]])
a4b2c4a1
```

A neat one liner :-)

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I like your the first variant as it's clear and simpler than mine. The second uses methods which I'm not  aware of.